# How set set multiple color columns / cc (:set colorcolumn) in vim?

Tags: vim, vi

A single colorcolumn can be set like this:

```
:set colorcolumn=80
```

How can I set multiple colorcolumns (e.g., at columns 40 and 80)?

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: Fixed now.  Sorry, I had mistakenly put my answer in the question.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use commas as delimiters to specify multiple columns, e.g.,

```
:set colorcolumn=40,80
```

-or-

```
:set cc=40,80
```

will set two colorcolumns, one at column 40 and one at column 80.

Also, `+=` and `-=` can be used to add/remove columns:

```
:set cc+=60
:set cc-=80
```

will add column 60 and remove column 80, so the columns will now be 40 and 60.

Comment: and you can add one with `:set cc+=40` or remove it with `-=`

Comment: Thank you @DoktorOSwaldo!  I've now added those to the answer.

Comment: It would be cool if you could also set different colors/transparencies for each column.